# How to access a method on a parent from a grandchild

Tags: vue.js

I am not sure what else to call this. I have a file, lets call it parent.vue. it has the following

PARENT.vue

```
<template>
  <input-box
    :room="currentRoom"
    v-on:messagesent="getMessages"
    class="dark:bg-gray-800 px-6 pb-6 pt-4 dark:border-t-2 dark:border-gray-600 bottom-0 sticky" />
</template>
```

```
method:
  getMessages() {
    axios.get('/chat/room/' + this.currentRoom.id + '/messages')
    .then(response => {
      this.messages = response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  },
```

Then I have a child which calls the v-on anytime something happens. The issue is, I need to call that from a child inside the child. "aka the grandchild" Inside the CHILD I have inside a method

```
this.$emit('messagesent');
```

How can I accomplish the same thing inside the grandchild.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was a blank moment on my part.

Using

```
this.$parent.$emit()
```

Gave me the ability to send it up the chain. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you want to maintain encapsulation. Grandparent is not supposed to know about grandchild. It knows about parent, but not that there are sub-components or how many. In principle, you can swap one implementation of grandparent out for another that doesn't have multiple layers. Or has even more layers to get to child. And you could put child into a top-level component.

You already know about the notion of a global event bus. A bus doesn't have to be global, though. You can pass it down the props chain. (You could use grandparent itself as the bus, but that would expose it to its children; better hygiene to make a real bus.)

This distinguishes top-level components from sub-components: a sub-component will receive a bus prop to perform the functions of the top-level component that it helps to implement. A top-level component will originate the bus.

For more details check out the below link

https://andrejsabrickis.medium.com/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

Comment: In this specific case, I am using a modal that pops up to add data to the child. so I am less concerned about encapsulation. When I complete my MVP and refactor some components ill revisit this but for now this accomplishes my goal

Comment: That was jus for your info, all I wanted to highlight is when the hierarchy goes beyond one level it's better to go with event bus